# How do you show the toolbar in Excel 2008 on Mac OS X Lion if it's hidden?

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, osx-lion, microsoft-excel-2008

In Snow Leopard and earlier, there was a "tic-tac" control in the top right of the window, but after upgrading to Lion, it's no longer there. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: RIP tic tac. You will be missed :'(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting `~/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.Excel.plist` restored the toolbar for me.

Answer (score 1):

The option to show/hide the toolbar is still in the **View** menu, or should be. I don't know about Excel 2008 specifically.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, that menu item isn't available in 2008 :\

Comment: My bad. It was in Excel 2011 which is why I put this up :)